# Asciitosvg drawings with artistmode?

Tags: artist-mode

As a team, we use asciitosvg in our documentation wiki to generate beautiful diagrams :
https://github.com/dhobsd/asciitosvg

I'd like to draw those using artistmode, but the shapes are slightly different. For instance, rectangle squares are '#', and not '+'

Is there a way to configure a new shape in artistmode ?

Comment: Sadly, I cannot help with the emacs portion, but I have recently finished up some work on the reimplementation in Go, which supports angled corners using the `+` character. Fixing this in the PHP version would've required a rewrite, and I'm still surprised I managed to put 2.5k lines of PHP together into something marginally useful in the first place. I'm not offering this as a solution, because I don't know anything about emacs, and this doesn't answer your specific question. But perhaps you can elide this issue completely using https://github.com/asciitosvg/asciitosvg.

Comment: Great news, thank you for this work. I guess, in some time, the dokuwiki plugin will allow to use your go implementation, and we will be ables to use artist-mode's diagrams out of the box.

Comment: Sure! Please let me know in GitHub issues if you run into any issues or have ideas/feature requests. I do want to keep this maintained. I’m aware of some rendering nits currently, but am hoping to sort those out soon.